# Jsoup efficient way to remove html elements and children's

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to remove html `div` and `table` tables tags and anything inside it(childs), what's the best way to do it ?

I tried traversing the document like this but it's not working, in Jsoup documentation it says that `node.remove()` removes the element from the DOM and his children's:

```
doc.traverse(new NodeVisitor() {
                @Override
                public void head(Node node, int i) {

                }

                @Override
                public void tail(Node node, int i) {
                    //Log.i(TAG,"node: "+node.nodeName());
                    if( node.nodeName().compareTo("table") == 0 ||
                            node.nodeName().compareTo("div") == 0 )
                       node.remove();

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried the `remove()` function of the [Elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#remove%28%29) class?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select("div").remove();
doc.select("table").remove();
```

This should select and remove all `<div>` and `<table>` elements.

Comment: the remove from elements class don´t remove the children's i think. I'm gonna check it again however.

Comment: @SergioSerra it worked on a simple example for me (e.g. I had some divs with text and a paragraph and a table with some rows), but there could be some cases where it doesn't work.

Comment: You are right it works like you said, i was doing a stupid mistake, not getting the html from the doc like i should, didn't notice it before. It now works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select("table *").remove();
```